# Quero abrir os containers de maneira separada usando JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sou novo em Jquery e queria saber se existe uma forma de utilizar o código que criei (sinceramente não sei se isso ta certo mas ta funcionando) pra abrir os containers separadamente pois quando realizo a ação eles abrem todos juntos.

```
{let container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(container).mouseenter(function(){ 
      $(container).addClass('mouseenter');
    });
    $(container).mouseleave(function(){ 
      $(container).removeClass('mouseenter');
  });})}
```

já tentei fazer só no css com :hover mas ele fica falhando na maioria das vezes.

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta mas pelo que entendi de sua lógica você tem vários containers e gostaria de que cada um tivesse uma ação diferente quando o mouse estivesse em cima correto?

Se eu estiver correto, você pode melhorar seu código da seguinte forma

- utilize o selector padrão do jQuery para manter um padrão no seu código

  var containersList = $(".container")

isso vai te dar uma lista com todos os elementos com a classe container
para estar loopando por todos o jQuery facilitou a manobra com a função `each()`

entao você pode estar aplicando sua lógica seguindo essa ideia

```
var containerList = $(.container)
containerList.each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass('mouseenter');
    })
})
```